# api route handler html response

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to login callback that returns html and sets value on `localStorage`. But returning html response is not executing it appears inside of `pre` tag

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = () => {
  return new NextResponse('<script>localStorage.setItem("authToken", "authToken");window.location.assign("/");</script>');
};
```

Response i'm having:

```html
<html>
<head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
&lt;script&gt;localStorage.setItem("authToken", "authToken");window.location.assign("/");&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Response i want:

```html
<html>
<head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head>
<body>
   <script>localStorage.setItem("authToken", "authToken");window.location.assign("/")</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in pages handler i can do this it will we work fine:

```js
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  return res.send('<script>localStorage.setItem("authToken", "authToken");window.location.assign("/");</script>');
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the endpoints, and how you are rendring the result?

Comment: i have been calling it like this [http://example.com/api/auth/callback](http://example.com/api/auth/callback) just regular get request

Comment: You would want to send the token as JSON for example, and set the cookie and redirect in the client.